# How to apply same style to all the textbox's at visual state setters in a single setter using uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to apply same width to all the textbox's. So if the screen size changes then I need to change the textboxs width. For that I want apply a style in a single setter at visual state (xaml).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is not how I recommend doing this. Your layout should dictate sizes, not the children of it. So for example if you have them in a grid, the grid should be able to be any size and the buttons in it would grow/shrink to fill the space provided.

Comment: Did you check my answer? Any question?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Chris W, and if I didn't misunderstand your question, you wanted to create one single style for all the `TextBox`s and you want to change the width in this style when window's size changed.

If you insist to design your layout in this way, you can create a `VisualStateGroup` in the default template style of `TextBox` for example like this:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <!--<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />-->
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                    ...
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                           ...                                
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                           ...
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Mobile">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="BorderElement.Width" Value="250" />
                                    <Setter Target="HeaderContentPresenter.Width" Value="250" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentElement.Width" Value="210" />
                                    <Setter Target="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter.Width" Value="250" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PC">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="BorderElement.Width" Value="450" />
                                    <Setter Target="HeaderContentPresenter.Width" Value="450" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentElement.Width" Value="410" />
                                    <Setter Target="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter.Width" Value="450" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="0,0,0,8" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy" />
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollVie
                    <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}" MinWidth="34" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}" V
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And you can apply this style in all your textboxs for example like this:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Height="100" />
```